# What's the purpose of unsigned type here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry for the multitude of iPhone Programming newb questions but..

what is the reason for having an unsigned type for something such as

```
- (unsigned)count
```

for the NSArray class.

Why not just define it as

```
- (int)count
```

?

Comment: Newb questions are fine, even encouraged.  If you don't know something, chances are high that someone else will have the same question.  Please stop putting tags in your titles though.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: I just noticed that, thanks for editing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array can't have a negative number of items, so an unsigned integer is a much better match for the kinds of values this method will actually return.